# How to separate node modules from async chunks in webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, lazy-loading, webpack-2

My webpack config has vendor chunk, which is separated from main bundle. However, since I'm using lazy loading on routes as well, I need to be able to separate rest of node modules from those lazy loading chunks also. I tried with this:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      async: 'used-twice',
      // children: true,
      minChunks(module, count) {
          return count >= 2;
      },
  }),
```

but it does nothing.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated webpack version to 3.10.0 and it works.